# Tamanho de arrays

Tags: java, array, java-processing

Se a teoria diz que o tamanho de um array não pode ser alterado, somente os elementos. Porque quando eu imprimo o tamanho de `a` o valor é 10 e não 5 ou 15?

```
int[] a;
    a = new int[5];
    a = new int[10];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não mudou o tamanho do vetor, você o instanciou novamente com um vetor de tamanho maior.

Answer (score 4):

No exemplo que você deu deve-se ter em mente que `a` é um ponteiro para um Array e não o próprio Array.
Assim, no momento que você fez `a = new int[10]` o `a` que antes apontava para um Array de tamanho 5 agora passou a apontar para o Array de tamanho 10.

E o que aconteceu com o Array de tamanho 5?

A partir do momento em que o array não tem ninguém apontando para si, ele está está pronto pra ser desalocado pelo Garbage Collector.

Comment: Faz muito sentido.